# Core Data ManagedObjectContext lock/unlock

Tags: ios, core-data, locking

When would you want to lock the Core Data context?

I'm having an issue where an operation is happening as a result of a network operation, and at the same time, there is some user input, both to the same data. This causes a conflict and data ends up being lost.

I tried wrapping the sensitive code from the network operation in `@synchronized`, and also with `[context lock]` and `[context unlock]`, but that doesn't solve the problem.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Instead, you could create two contexts, one for network input and one for user input, and then merge them into the store instead of locking and writing to the same one.

Comment: Even with two contexts, wouldn't there still be conflicts?

Comment: In case of more context, you have to synchronize the persistence store  coordinator, then do the merge and save.

Comment: Or you could manage access to the context with a serial private queue, a lot easier that using locks.